# How to use logger with one basic config across app in Python

Tags: python, logging

I want to improve my understanding of how to use logging correctly in Python. I want to use `.ini` file to configure it and what I want to do:

- define basic logger config through `.fileConfig(...)` in some `.py` file
- `import logger`, call `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` across the app and be sure that it uses my config file that I was loaded recently in different `.py` file

I read few resources over Internet ofc but they are describing tricks of how to configure it etc, but want I to understand is that `.fileConfig` works across all app or works only for file/module where it was declared.
Looks like I missed some small tip or smth like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works across the whole app. Be sure to configure the correct loggers in the config. `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` works well if you know how to handle having a different logger in every module, otherwise you might be happier just calling `logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")` which always gives you the same logger. If you only configure the root logger you might even skip that and simply use `logging.info("message")` directly.